# Xcode build fails with error in GoogleDataTransport

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

My iOS application has been building fine for several months.   And then, suddenly my project builds are now failing with an error "A function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C".

[image]

**What has changed**: I moved my project from an external drive to my internal drive

**What I have done to attempt to mitigate**:

1. Reinstalled Xcode
2. Cloned my project from github and rebuilt it

Also, I am no longer able to build from the original directory on my external drive

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you @Joel Stevick. Your answer help me but the only step that worked for me is to update specific repository which is GoogleDataTransport. So I have just follow below step and my issue is resolved:

```
pod update GoogleDataTransport
```

I hope this might help anyone.

Comment: @SpeakDevelopment, You can try the same again after deleting DerivedData. The steps should be: 1. Quite xCode, 2. Empty DerivedData Folder. 3. Remove the same from Bin. 4. Update the specific pod using the above command, or you can update all pods by using the "pod update" command. This will update all your pods 5. Now you can open your project and your build will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem as follows:

1. cd to the project app folder
2. change the Podfile entries:

- pod 'Firebase/Auth' => pod 'Firebase/Auth', '10.7.0'
- pod 'Firebase/Messaging => pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '10.7.0'

3. run "pod install --repo-update"

**Then**

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete the project's temp files located at
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
4. Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
5. Run pod install.
6. Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.